# Which version is better and why in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
if(a != b) {
    a=b;
}
```

or

```
a=b;
```

We don't know if a and b are equal or not.

Comment: Please go through: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can delete your own question. If you look under your question you should see a clickable link "delete". Click that and confirm that you do want to delete it.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2):

Use the shorter `a = b`.

An assignment is computationally cheap (for built-in types), probably no more expensive than the comparison test. See for yourself: check the generated machine code.

But avoid such micro-optimsations: write what is clearest. And profile the performance if you believe your code has bottlenecks that could be optimised out.